# Inverse Laplace transform in matlab

Tags: matlab

Which command do I use to get the original function `f(t)` from its Laplace transform?

i.e, I plug the Laplace transform in the `s` variable and I want to get `f(t)`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`ilaplace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ilaplace.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab, you can use the `ilaplace` function, which computes the Inverse Laplace Transform. As usual, the Matlab documentation is pretty good:

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/symbolic/ilaplace.html